# Producing "chandrabindu-halanth" symbol in devanagari

Tags: fonts, packages, characters

[image]

Can the above image be produced using the `devanagari` package. To produce it I used the `skt` package but I am curious to know if this image (that is the chandrabindu along with the halanth) can be producing in the `devanagari` package. This symbol very often is used in the "Rudram: Namakam-Camakam" mantra.

Answer (score 5):

`{\dn\dnsamaveda hi\@\ }`. But you need a font including the last character (`U+A8F3 DEVANAGARI SIGN CANDRABINDU VIRAMA`). There seems to be only [Siddhanta](http://svayambhava.org/index.php/en/sanskrit/fonts).

Comment: Thanks martin. That does work but the "candrabindu-virama" is a little upside though

Comment: are you using itranslator or latex? xelatex does lot better rendering of devanagari text. there you don't have to type in roman text and then convert it to devanagari. With xelatex you can directly type in Devangari in your tex editor. however if you are using to transliterate so that you can later convert it to different indian languages then its a different story. I used "Sanskrit 2003" font and it gives a good sanskrit text out. I might post an example later.

Comment: @Aku Can you post a MWE for inputting Chandrabindu?

Answer (score 0):

To add chandrabindu, just hold ALT key and type 0161  i.e. ALT + 0161.(in Devlys 010 Fonts)

Answer (score 0):

This character can be easily got if you download an unicode map. You also have to have either the chandas or siddhanta fonts installed to be able to view it.